# How to setup Hibernate cascade correctly

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-cascade

I have following setup

A -> B -> C

**A-Mapping:**

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="db.base.A" table="A">
      <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
          <column name="id" />        
          <generator class="identity" />    
      </id>
      <set name="Bs" table="BI18n" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
          <key>
              <column name="A_id"  not-null="true" />
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="db.base.B" />
      </set>        
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**B:**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="db.base.B" table="B">
      <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
          <column name="id" />
          <generator class="identity" />
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="A" class="db.base.A" fetch="select">
          <column name="A_id" not-null="true" />
      </many-to-one>
      <set name="B" table="B" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
          <key>
              <column name="id" not-null="true" />
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="db.base.BI18n" />
      </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**SubstanceItentifiedI18n:**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="db.base.BI18n" table="B18n">
      <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
          <column name="id" />
          <generator class="identity" />
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="B" class="db.base.B" fetch="select">
          <column name="id" not-null="true" />
      </many-to-one>          
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I insert a new A with the complete object graph via

```
HibernateDaoSupport.merge(AObj);
```

everything is created correctly.

But if I use

```
HibernateDaoSupport.saveOrUpdate(AObj);
```

I get a `DataIntegrityException`

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`table`.`B18n`, CONSTRAINT `B18n_fk` 
FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `B` (`id`))
```

When I look in the log4j log I see that with `merge`

1. it inserts `B`
2. it inserts `B18n`

With `saveOrUpdate` it

1. inserts `B18n`, which obviously results in the exception

is this defined (expected) behavior or is there something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Are you sure that every association is initialized properly, in both directions (i.e. is seizure has a substanceIdentified, then this substanceIdentified should point to the seizure, and vice-versa)?

Comment: yeah this is actually generated by Jackson. I feed Jackson with JSON data and it generates the whole object graph for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling a found out what the solution was.

I was adding new elements to an existing `B`. But didn't set the id of the `B`, because merge does a `SELECT` of the object graph before it issues a save/update this is no problem.

`saveOrUpdate` on the other hand doesn't do it. Therefore the exception.

Case closed ;)